# is it possible to add inline image in mail body in android or embedded image in mail body from drawable ?

Tags: android, email, send

I have converted drawable into base64 but it did not work, instead of image it showing [OBJ]

Answer (score 0):

You can't add image inside body. you can use `HTML` and format your text and other thing.
http://www.nowherenearithaca.com/2011/10/some-notes-for-sending-html-email-in.html

Comment: You need to write your own Html.ImageGetter for this to work - I've haven't messed with this yet