# How can I embedd Images in Email Body- Android

Tags: java, android, email

I have read many posts and see there is not a exact answer for this, were any of you able to figure out how we can embed images in email body in Android

Comment: I'ts better if you could post some code of what you've done so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can't embed an image inside the email body.

This question has been answered before.Are you facing the same problem?

[is it possible to add inline image in mail body in android or embedded image in mail body from drawable ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901145/is-it-possible-to-add-inline-image-in-mail-body-in-android-or-embedded-image-in)